# How to get the whole number before the space?

Tags: python

I want to extract the last number from my file:

```
::1 - - [18/Jan/2017:09:01:08 +0530] "GET /music/create_album/ HTTP/1.1" 200  5857
::1 - - [19/Jan/2017:22:29:46 +0530] "GET /button/button1.js HTTP/1.1" 404 4663
```

This is my file and I want only the last number 4663.
and split function gives an error.
So I used:

```
f = open("access.log.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    l = line.rstrip('\t')
print(l[-10:])
```

but it shows 404 4663. I want the whole number after the space.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the line, get the chars which are digits, reverse the result:

```
>>> text = 'abc 1234'
>>> ends = ''
>>> for ch in text[::-1]:
...     if ch.isdigit(): 
...         ends +=ch
...     else:
...         break
>>> ends[::-1]
'1234'
```

You can try with RegEx, but I'm not sure if it will be faster